# Winform Data Grid View Dynamically fill box space

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a 4 column grid (in a group box if that matters) where one of the columns can vary from Column header width to 75 characters. I am trying to figure out a way to fill the last column only if the collective widths of the columns do not require horizontal scrolling.

```
dgvView.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
        dgvView.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
        dgvView.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
        dgvView.Columns[3].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
```

my issue is, if I just convert dgvView.Columns[3] to .Fill, large text from dgvView.Columns[2] crunches the text from dgvView.Columns[3]. When I just keep it at DisplayedCells, if the text is too small it does not full fill the grid box and it does not look good. 
Is there a way to make it work both way?

Comment: Did you notice/check out the various [AutoSizeMode modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.autosizemode(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: Why not using allCells, columns will then set their width based on widest cell.

Comment: Unfortunately that is the problem. If the widest cell is very short, there will still be an empty area at the end of the last column.

Comment: I ended up with a combination of set column widths and a .Fill on the last column. It is not perfect, but it was the best compromise I could make

Comment: ooooh i get it now. Why do not get width of DGW and divide it by `nColumns` and set that value as Column width?

Comment: That is another option. I chose a similar solution that removed extra white space and added to the specific column that needs the extra space.